# How to update/pre-populate Rails form using a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to create a form with dropdown where users can create a new object if something like "Create new" is selected, or they have the option of choosing from their previously created objects, which should prefill the form with the corresponding data.

At the moment I simply have a for each loop filling the dropdown list with the previously created objects which is outside the form, and a form that creates new objects.

How can I make this form dynamic so that when a previously selected object is selected, the form pre-fills and allows for editing?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to send out an AJAX GET request to a custom route and then have a controller action that responds to `json` format and returns a collection based on params passed in that GET request. Say, you are loading available car models based on a selected make:

routes:

```
get '/get_models/:make_id', to: 'car_makes#available_models'
```

controller action:

```
def available_models
  @models = Model.where(id: ids)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @models } 
  end
end
```

AJAX request:

```
var fetchModels = function(makeId){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url:     '/get_models/' + makeId,
    success: function(data) {
      ...
      var target = $('select#car_models');  // field to which options are appended
      $.each(data, function(id, model){
        $(target).append(
          $('<option>').text(model).attr('value', id) // populate options             );
      });
    }
    ...
  });
}
```

and then setting the AJAX request to fire on `.change` event in a parent `select` field:

```
$('select#car_makes').change(function(){
   var makeId = $(this).val();
   fetchModels(makeId); 
});
```

There are a number of resources explaining other ways to achieve this:

- https://gorails.com/episodes/jquery-ujs-and-ajax
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised

Comment: So I understand and get this for the most part, the disconnect I have is between how to use this information in conjunction with a rails form that can then edit the object that was selected and save it.

Comment: From what I can tell all this does is let one choose a car make and then update another dropdown for the available car models. To continue with your analogy, I need one to be able to select a car make, and then be able to make changes to the attribute of the car make object, such as the name, in a form that is populated with its attributes, then save it.

Comment: So you want visitors to have one select with `makes` collection, then once a make is selected, fields with attributes of the `make` objects are appended to the same form. Correct?

Comment: I think so, yes. It may help to look at my not-so-great solution if I am not explaining adequately

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up looping through all of the potential options for the select dropdown, and looping through the edit rails form with all the potential options, and using jQuery onchange to show / hide the correct html.

This doesn't feel like a very good solution to me, especially as it has to load the html of all the options every time.. but I don't know what else to do and it works.

If anyone has any ideas for a better solution, let me know :)